# ag-grid using row grouping not filtering client-side when rowModelType=serverSide and serverSideStoreType=full

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

According to the AG Grid (v25) documentation (https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/server-side-model-filtering/) filtering should happen client-side (or in the grid as per their documentation) when using rowModelType=serverSide and serverSideStoreType=full. However my example below which uses row grouping too, does not filter client-side.

This plunker demonstrates the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/GjjaqzQKwNxk3xc4

This is actually a modified official AG-Grid plunker taken from their documentation and modified to demonstrate the problem.

For SO: Here's a snippet of the code:

```
this.serverSideStoreType = 'full';
this.rowModelType = 'serverSide';
```

And here's the filter definition on the Sport column:

```
{
  field: 'sport',
  enableRowGroup: true,
  rowGroup: true,
  filter: 'agSetColumnFilter', 
  filterParams: {
    values: ['Gymnastics', 'Swimming', 'Athletics']
  }
}
```

Data is grouped by Country then Sport. I have placed a set filter on Sport. Expand "United States" and then proceed to place a filter on Sport, you will notice the filter does not affect the expanded sports under United States.

Answer (score 0):

I too have wanted to understand what's happening here.

Did you ever figure this out or use a workaround?

On both your example and the example given by the docs (https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/server-side-model-filtering/), it appears that once you remove the `rowGroup=true`, the full store filter starts to function, but does not function once grouping is applied.

One other example in the Pivoting section of SSRM uses partial store. This seems to work because you then control the `filterModel` in the grid request. Selecting and unselecting filter checks triggers a grid request with `filterModel` set. I think I might do this but it does require a lot more work to wire your request to the backend.

https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=index.jsx&preview